# adding boost library to clion on MacOsX

Tags: c++, boost

Hello i installed boost using comand
brew install boost
it installed 1.66.0 version
I edited CMakeLists in this way

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(fraction)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp source/Fraction.cpp headers/Fraction.h headers/MyStack.h unitTest.cpp)
add_executable(fraction ${SOURCE_FILES})


set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.66.0")
find_package(Boost 1.66.0)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()
```

I don't have any error, in file unitTest.cpp I want to write test and I'm trying to include this

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
```

but I got error "Cannot find 'boost'"
What I do wrong ?

Comment: Did you install boost on your system?

Comment: yes using brew install boost

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find why it doesn't work, brew didn't link boost
on high sierra it should be in this way
if usr/local/include and usr/local/Frameworks don't exist it must be created by

```
sudo mkdir usr/local/include
sudo mkdir usr/local/Frameworks
```

after that we can chown usr/local/include by

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```